# Behat not calling jQuery

Tags: jquery, behat

I use behat in symfony 4 to test the sending of a message. When you select the subject "Other", a new field is displayed from jQuery. When I test this code live, there is no problem. But from behat, jQuery is not called. Behat selects the correct "other" option, but the new field doesn't appear.

Here is the step in the scenrario :

```
/**
 * @Given /^I choose the subject "([^"]*)" in select "([^"]*)"$/
 * @param $topic
 * @param $select
 */
public function iSelectTheSubject($topic, $select)
{
  $this->selectOption($select, $topic);
}
```

And here is my jQuery :

```
(function ($) {
            let selectSubject = $('#app_customer_service_taxon option');
            let inputOther = $('#app_customer_service_taxonOther').parent();
            let options = {
                action: 'click',
                html : 'other'
            };

            inputOther.hide();
            selectSubject.on(options.action, e => {
                $(e.currentTarget).html() === options.html ? inputOther.show() : inputOther.hide();
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

So when I start behat, it stops with the message "element not interactable". It's like jQuery is not called at all. Like the selectOption did not simulate the click. Any idea why ?

Comment: `selectOption` is a default method or it's something you defined, if custom please provide the code. Seems that check if can interact with the element, and fails since it overlapped by something else or hidden. As an alternative you could also implement a select with jQuery/JavaScript or add a wait until is the element is loaded/interactable.

Comment: What driver are you using with behat? chromedrive/selenium? Also, sometimes when toggling elements you might have to wait for a short time until the DOM changes. You can find examples online for waiting in behat, e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jmauerhan/f839926ea527ff5e74e7).